# SOLR IDF Max docs configuration

Tags: search, solr, tf-idf

I'm using SOLR for storing the documents used by search in my application. The SOLR is shared by multiple applications and the data is grouped based on the application id which is unique for each application.

For calculating the score based on TF-IDF the SOLR uses the total documents available in it. How do I change that configuration to check the IDF only based on the total documents available for the application id rather than counting all the documents across applications.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you store all docs in one collection, there is still something you can do!

Unless you enable [ExactStatsCache](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Requests) in your solrconfig.xml like this:

```
<statsCache class="org.apache.solr.search.stats.ExactStatsCache"/>
```

similarity calculations are per shard, not per total collection.

So, if you shard your docs by your application_id, then you will get 'better' scores, closer to that you want. It will be exactly what you want *if you get one application_id per shard*, but if you have many applications and not many shards you will get more than one app per shard.

Answer (score 1):

If you store them in one collection, I am afraid it's not possible with built-in functionality.

I think you have several choices - store each application data in the separate collection, than you will have IDF based only on specific application data out of the box.

If this is not suitable for you - you will need to write your own Similarity, probably by exteding https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html and overriding method `public abstract float idf(long docFreq, long docCount)` which is responsible for calculating IDF

Overall, I think the first approach will suit your needs much better.